# Rename the worksheet based on excel cell value

Tags: excel, vba, rename, worksheet

I try to change the worksheet tab name based excel cell value but when i try to run the code its asking create a macro please help

I created one more sub but not workd

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Specify the target cell whose entry shall be the sheet tab name.
    If Target.Address <> "$A$2" Then Exit Sub
        'If the target cell is empty (contents cleared) then do not change the shet name
    If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    'If the length of the target cell's entry is greater than 31 characters, disallow the entry.
    If Len(Target.Value) > 21 Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet tab names cannot be greater than 31 characters in length." & vbCrLf & _
        "You entered " & Target.Value & ", which has " & Len(Target.Value) & " characters.", , "Keep it under 21 characters"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Sheet tab names cannot contain the characters /, \, [, ], *, ?, or :.
    'Verify that none of these characters are present in the cell's entry.
    Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer
    IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
    IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
    IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
    IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
    IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
    IllegalCharacter(6) = "?"
    IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"
    For i = 1 To 7
        If InStr(Target.Value, (IllegalCharacter(i))) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "You used a character that violates sheet naming rules." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please re-enter a sheet name without the ''" & IllegalCharacter(i) & "'' character.", 48, "Not a possible sheet name !!"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    'Verify that the proposed sheet name does not already exist in the workbook.
    Dim strSheetName As String, wks As Worksheet, bln As Boolean
    strSheetName = Trim(Target.Value)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not wks Is Nothing Then
        bln = True
    Else
        bln = False
        Err.Clear
    End If

    'If the worksheet name does not already exist, name the active sheet as the target cell value.
    'Otherwise, advise the user that duplicate sheet names are not allowed.
    If bln = False Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = strSheetName
    Else
        MsgBox "There is already a sheet named " & strSheetName & "." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please enter a unique name for this sheet."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code in a regular module or in a sheet code module?

Comment: Regular code referred from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/name-a-worksheet-by-using-a-cell-value

Comment: `Sub Worksheet_Change` is the [Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event code and goes in a sheet code module. Right click on the sheet tab, click *View Code* and paste the code there.

Comment: its asking create a macro

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want.

```
Sub RenameSheet()

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xRngAddress As String
Dim xName As String
xRngAddress = Application.ActiveCell.Address
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    xName = xWs.Range(xRngAddress).Value
    If xName <> "" Then
        xWs.Name = xName
    End If
Next
End Sub
```